# Manual routing or FriendlyId?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'd like to accomplish an URL structure which would look something like this:

- `/comics` - lists all the comics in the database (actually this could be a portal page showing featured comics, most popular comic, etc)
- `/comics/{comic-name}` - lists all the strips in the given comic (possibly paged)
- `/comics/{comic-name}/feed` - provides an RSS feed for the strips in the comic
- `/comics/{comic-name}/{strip-id}` - shows a strip belonging to the comic

Should I go with FriendlyId or should I use manual routing? Whatever your pick please provide the routes.rb snippet.

Thanks!

Comment: Choose what you prefer, both technic works fine.

Comment: OK, I'll get working then, will try to answer my own question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will go for manual routing. With friendlyID, you can get up and go easily but when your app starts becoming complex and you begin customizations, you might as well started without FriendlyID (depending on the depth of customizations you have to do)

Comment: Indeed, judging from my experience with various PHP frameworks plus knowing that routes can get complicated and not wanting to wrestle with FriendlyID later just to bend it to my will I went with the manual approach.

Comment: good choice! such solutions may be good in showing the _eloquence_ of a solution to a beginner class but in implementation, the manual way is better. This reminds me of Rails' scaffolding; not many people use that nowadays